# MySQL: Not show results NULL into JOIN LEFT/RIGTH

Tags: mysql, select, join, left-join

I done in that way:

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
               SELECT DISTINCT (u2.email) email FROM  `users` u1 LEFT JOIN 
                       users u2 ON  u1.email = u2.email AND u1.id <> u2.id
               )users  WHERE email IS NOT NULL
```

Is there a contract formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an INNER JOIN if you don't want NULL results.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(u2.email) FROM users u1 
    INNER JOIN users u2 ON u1.email = u2.email AND u1.id <> u2.id
```

If you must use a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(u2.email) FROM users u1 
    LEFT JOIN users u2 ON u1.email = u2.email AND u1.id <> u2.id 
    WHERE u2.email IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Almost the same way as the INNER JOIN then. I've edited my answer response with the LEFT JOIN method.